# Multiple Order management systems vs single OMS

Tags: architecture, microservices, e-commerce, software-design, system-design

I have a use case where I need to be able to sell different types of unrelated services and products on my platform and I need to create order management systems for these items.

One way I can think of is to create separate OMS systems per product/service type and expose these functionalities to an app. The other way is to create 1 common OMS (a company wide OMS) and have the concept of line items where the line items are grouped by the type and then processed.

The advantage of the first system is decoupling (I think), the cons are that as the type of services grow, the number of OMSes will increase. The advantage of the second system is that it creates a single OMS across the company and any expansion just needs new workflow plugins.

At a system level, what should be the preferred way to go? I am also keeping the different OMSes as separate micro-services, so having one big OMS might be a single point of failure. What should be the right way to proceed?

P.S. payments is a big part of this and we need to also accommodate for different payment workflows (strict prepaid vs postpaid vs hybrid) too.

Answer (score 0):

Just the fact that you refer to each system as an OMS implies they have the same functionality and should be the same system.  You shouldn't create separate systems because the data is different.  You create different systems because the required functions are different.  Any separation and processing of data is handled by the features in the software.

Comment: Thank you for your input, Brad. much appreciated.